# Sending Emails on console errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Research I have done for this question and links:

[How do you send console messages and errors to alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253652/how-do-you-send-console-messages-and-errors-to-alert)

[jQuery AJAX form using mail() PHP script sends email, but POST data from HTML form is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300470/jquery-ajax-form-using-mail-php-script-sends-email-but-post-data-from-html-fo)

The code example:

```
function handleError(evt) {
  if (evt.message) { // Chrome sometimes provides this
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: evt.message,
            success: function(){
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
  } else {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: evt.type,
            success: function(){
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Question) What type of validation is required in "email.php" to be sure that the emails aren't malicious (to the extent that this is possible) IE: is there a vulnerability that you are exposing yourself to with this function.
If there is a built in mechanism for changing the location of error logs in javascript, that too would answer this question.

Comment: Won't be anything to validate in php if you don't send key/value pairs for `$_POST` to see. No idea what the last part means about `location of logs`

Comment: Do you mean to quote 'If there is a built in mechanism for changing the location of error logs in javascript, that too would answer this question.'?

If so, to clarify: 
I am under the assumption that uncaught errors in javascript will go to the console error log. I am attempting to catch the errors that go to this console error log. Is this the only function to capture uncaught error events that occur in the window, or is there another mechanism?
Let me know if that clears that statement up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're sending it to a known email address so checking the email isn't required?

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Then clean the data to be sent from anything that makes your email stop from functioning properly.

```
function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$data = clean_string($data);
```

After that strip the html tags to prevent html from being sent(prevents javascript from being sent as example).

```
$data = strip_tags($data);
```

The data should be safe to send in a email now keep in mind the data is not safe yet to be sent to a sql database, if you do sent it to a databse use prepared statements so the data can't do any sql injections.