# Retrieve console through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to send back the latest errors/log statements from the console as part of a support-request. I do I retrieve the console through javascript/jquery?

Comment: Use try.... catch

Comment: Also, you could override `console` and have it submit calls via AJAX

Comment: Try this! => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253652/how-do-you-send-console-messages-and-errors-to-alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch all javascript errors and send them to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server)

Comment: @Rajesh OP says *"log statements"* too so just catching errors wouldn't be enough

Comment: My bad! I'll retract my vote

Comment: @Rajesh I'd leave the link though, it's a good one. This question is really too broad

Comment: I have actually answered similar question overriding all console functions but its lost. Digging through answers. Will share if found

Comment: @Phil This will help. Didn't find related answer but found fiddle link. **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pwrth00/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the `console.log`

```
(function(){
    if(window.console && console.log){
        var old = console.log;
        console.log = function(){
            doSomthingElse(arguments); 
            old.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }  
})();
```

Comment: What about all the other [`console` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console#Methods)?

Comment: You need to do it one by one.
Here is fully article about override `console` methods
http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/104/how-to-override-the-console-methods-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [try... catch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/j3tfLukr/

```
var a = {}

try {
   var b = a.b.c
} catch(e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

Comment: This will cover only that part of code that is written by you

Comment: To clarify, your code will not cover issues like `$ in undefined` which happens because of delayed loading or accessing `$` before loading jQuery

Comment: @Rajesh - I would also like to cover issues like $ is undefined as some parts of the application is quite old. Would that be possible? I can see it in the developer console and now I would "just" like to retrieve that :-)

Comment: @user1697073 for errors, I would suggest using sentry, as mentioned in duplicate I shared under question. If you want to handle manually, I have also shared a JSFiddle link that does something similar, but make sure this script loads before anything else